# What does asterisk indicate in DB2 explain plan

Tags: db2, explain

I have generated an explain plan using db2expln but looking at the plan one of the table is joined with asterisk; what does it indicate?

Optimizer Plan:

```
                              Rows
                            Operator
                              (ID)
                              Cost

                            0.207027
                              n/a
                             RETURN
                              ( 1)
                            46.9844
                               |
                            0.207027
                              n/a
                             NLJOIN
                              ( 2)
                            46.9842
                     /-----/        \----------\
                 1                              *
                n/a                         /--/ \
               FETCH                0.207027     3.32776e+07
               ( 3)                   n/a            n/a
              37.8331                IXSCAN      Table:
          /--/       \                ( 6)        S01
      1            1.58636e+08      15.1458      FA
     n/a               n/a            |
    IXSCAN         Table:         3.24166e+07
     ( 4)           S01             Index:
    30.269         ID     S01
      |                         FT_STA_IDX21
 1.58636e+08
Index:
S01
IT_DIDAL_IDX0
```

Answer (score 1):

As with dash, forward slash and backslash, the asterisk is just another character occasionally used by [`db2expln`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0005736.html) to draw a connection between two operations in an optimizer plan graph. The asterisk does not represent any significant action by itself. One way to confirm this is to submit the same SQL statement to the Visual Explain utility in IBM Data Studio so you can compare its vector-drawn optimizer plan graph with the ASCII plan generated by `db2expln -g`.